# = sign in a katakana name

Tags: katakana, names, punctuation

I was surprised when I came across this Wikipedia page:
[アーシュラ・K・ル＝グウィン](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BBK%E3%83%BB%E3%83%AB%EF%BC%9D%E3%82%B0%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3)

Does someone knows what that = sign is? I can see it works as a separator like 「・」 Is it simply an alternative?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's a [double hyphen](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%80%E3%83%96%E3%83%AB%E3%83%8F%E3%82%A4%E3%83%95%E3%83%B3), not an equals sign.

One of its uses is when transliterating names that have a hyphen in them. This is to avoid confusion with the extended sound symbol (`ー`) in Japanese.  For example: `クロード・レヴィ＝ストロース (Claude Lévi-Strauss)`

Another time when the double hyphen is used is when in the original language, there is a stop in the sound. Your example fits this case. `アーシュラ・K・ル＝グウィン (Ursula Kroeber Le Guin)`. In English there's a very obvious stop after `Le`.

Now you might ask why use the double hyphen instead of `・` (the [interpunct](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E9%BB%92)). After all, `・` is used way more often in nearly all cases as noted [here](http://www.raitonoveru.jp/howto/p3.html):  　`中黒（・）を用いるのが一般的だが、厳密な規定は無い。`.  It seems that it mostly depends on whether the text is vertical or horizontal.

For vertical text, `・` is preferred overwhelmingly. For horizontal texts, `゠` can be used instead, although people still generally use `・`. Source: [The best answer from here](http://q.hatena.ne.jp/1322033268)

Comment: I added a source for that.

Comment: Another use of the double hyphen, from Wikipedia- "It may also be used to separate a person's given and family names".