# Why Japanese “ Obi-Wan” is written as “ オビ＝ワン”?

Tags: english-to-japanese

In English, “obi-wan” is a “-“ in the middle, but Japanese translation “オビ＝ワン” is a “=“ in the middle. What makes this difference? Is this because “-“ looks like “ー” in katakana, so Japanese deliberately avoid it?

Please answer my question, I’ve been curious for a long time. **THANK YOU!**

[image: Wikipedia オビ＝ワン page]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27587/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61379/9831

Comment: Thank you Chocolate! It solved my question.